# Assigning to postfix-incremented pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, operators, rvalue

I have read that postfix increment and decrement operators return **rvalues** of the operands. Assuming that is true, how are codes like this possible?:

```
int arr[5]{};
int *p = arr;
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    *p++ = i;
```

My thought procees is

1. According to operator precendence, `*p` will get evaluated first.
2. Then postfix increment will increment the value and return **a copy of the object as an rvalue**.
3. Then I get confused because rvalues should not be on the left hand side of assignment operator...
   So my question basically is : how is `*p++ = i;` possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to operator precendence, `*p` will get evaluated first.

You are mistaken. According to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the increment will be evaluated first. This will yield an rvalue (i.e. the value of the pointer before it got incremented), which then, after it get's dereferenced, is an *lvalue* you can assign to.

Comment: Ah of course. I got dot operator and dereference operator mixed up. Seems so silly now. Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer Jodocus, 1 min earlier than me! @ZylonD.Lite, do not forget to *accept* his answer.

Comment: Note that, although `p++` is evaluated before the dereference; the side-effect of operator++ may happen at various times. (It is not tied to the evaulation order)

Answer (score 3):

> According to operator precendence, *p will get evaluated first.

Wrong.

Here:

```
*p++
```

the increment will be evaluated first, and not the `*p`.

This gives an rvalue (the pointer's value), and after the dereference, this becomes an lvalue which you are able to assign to `i`.

You could rewrite your for loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    *p++ = i;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
```

to get a better view.

Comment: Yeah my bad. Long night. Thanks.